# iPhone "Trust this computer": How to re-trust

Tags: iphone, ios

I have just connected my iPhone (4s/iOS 7.1) to my old MacBook. When the "Trust this Computer" message came, I chose accidently No.
Is there a way to trust my mac evev whan I already said No?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Source: http://osxdaily.com/2014/03/24/trust-this-computer-alert-ios/

- Try disconnecting/reconnecting the phone;
- If that does not work, try going to iTunes, in the Preferences, Advanced, click the “Reset Warnings” button.

Answer (score 2):

Without iTunes, if unplugging and replugging does not work, switch USB ports.